# Slowly Changing Dimension in SSAS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas

I'm trying to design a cube that will let me look at monthly revenue over the past several years using SSAS. I've built the revenue fact table using a Type 2 SCD that results in the following table:

```
Account Number     MonthlyPayment     Start Date     End Date
102939              115               01/01/2001     03/31/2001
102939              75                04/01/2001     NULL
102940              107               02/01/2001     NULL
```

Now, I'm trying to figure out what my monthly revenue is for each month e.g.

```
01/01: 115 
02/01: 222 
05/01: 182
```

I've built a cube but it's only reporting revenue on specific months because it's linked on Start Date e.g.

```
01/01: 115
02/01: 107
02/01: 0 
04/01: 75
```

Apparently I'm missing something because all the links I've been able to find stop after building the fact table in SSIS and seem to imply that it's a piece of cake once the data is formatted correctly. Do I need to write an MDX calculated measure and if so how? Or is there something much simpler that I should be looking at.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That's not an easy call.

You're looking to define at cell level (aka row level) a new type that is Payment(amount, start, end) that when aggregated is taking a date to calculate the amount.

OLAP cubes are not designed to solve this kind of problems out of the box as they aggregate only basic types (double, int, booleans...). I don't know of any vendor doing this at this point in time.

The standard way would be to add for each month the amount :

```
Account Number     MonthlyPayment     Date     
102939              115               01/01/2001
102939              115               02/01/2001
102939              115               03/01/2001
102939              75                04/01/2001
...
102940              107               02/01/2001
102940              107               03/01/2001
102940              107               04/01/2001
...
```

The question of this solution is the number of original rows versus new rows (memory) and how to generate the 'new' table.

Another is finding a vendor that can partnership with you to better address this solution, if SSAS is not a must.

Comment: SSAS is a must due to the constraints of the project, and I could potentially duplicate the rows per your suggestion, but the number of accounts and the number of different measures which have a similiar structure means I'd like to find a simpler solution, if at all possible.

Comment: I you do not want to get the sum over multiple months you can try a many-2-many but this path is a dangerous one. E.g. the sum of MonthlyPayment for the full 2001 would be 115+75+107 (rows are not count twice). You'll still have to do start/end decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

You add a Time dimension that includes all the dates, even if they are not used by your fact table. [SSAS allows you to generate a Time dimension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174832.aspx) that includes a month column you can use in MDX queries.

I am sorry, I did not completely comprehend the problem you were defining.
I think you are going to have to denormalise the table into something like

```
Account Number     PaymentAmount     Payment Date     
102939              115               01/01/2001     
102939              115               02/01/2001     
102939              115               03/01/2001     
102939              75                04/01/2001     
102940              107               02/01/2001
```

That will end up simplifying that calculations, at a cost of table size.

Comment: I've added the Time dimension, but I'm having trouble tying it to the EndDate column and I'm not sure how to structure the MDX query because the Dates aren't available in the measure, also I'm pretty unfamiliar with MDX so I'm even sure where to start.